# Why is the user search so out of date?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, search, users

When I press "Users" right below the logo on the main page, I am presented with a search engine. Here I can type in the name of a user, and get a list of all users with that name.

I searched myself. First off, there are many users named "Arthur" (which isn't terribly surprising once you know that user names are not unique), but what surprises me is this:

[image: Me in the search engine]

That's me. I clicked it, and it went to my profile, so there's no doubt. However, I have a lot more than $1\,144$ reputation. What's going on here?

Comment: I think the default reputation timeframe is 1 month, for whatever reason (you can see the toggle in the upper right corner). So I think the 1,444 is your reputation change over the last month.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. I am just blind and didn't see the options in the top right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were only looking at the reputation earned during the current month:

[image: users by reputation in this month]

Click on the "all" to get cumulative reputation (modulo caching):

[image: users by reputation all time]

Comment: I'll accept in 8 minutes when the system lets me. +1 for Paint circles. I do them myself when I get the chance.